# UltiSnips does not map to ExpandsTrigger

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-ultisnips

I installed UltiSnips with Vundle by placing

```
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'¬
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
```

in my `.vimrc` as well as this as it says in the readme

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
```

I installed the plugin with `:PluginInstall` and after restarting vim I can see that the plugin is installed by `:UltiSnipsEdit` which opens a new window to add snippets. I added a basic example and save the file which is saved to the project directory in `./UltiSnips/html.snippets`

```
snippet nn
<header class="main-header"></header>
endsnippet
```

Now I expect `nn` to expand into my snippet content after writing it and hitting tab key. However, it did not happen. I tried disabling other plugins that I have installed and mapping expand trigger to a different key / keys but that did not work either. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: what does `set ft?` say?

Comment: if I run it while editing the file where I want to expand my snippet it returns `filetype=html`

Comment: Have you installed a Tab plugin (f.e. supertab)? do other snippets work?

Comment: No I do not have a supertab plugin, I also tried disabling other plugins in my `.vimrc` file and reloading vim, but the problem remained

Comment: have you tried a default snippet? move your snippets to `~/.vim/UltiSnips` and try again. I don't think the project folder will be searched.

Comment: Default snippets work. Saving my snippet to `~/.vim/UltiSnips/` worked like a charm, interesting why UltiSnips save snippets in current project by default. Can you please post your solution as an answer so I can mark it as correct? Cheers

Comment: Sure, i will add some useful infos in a moment

Comment: Might have to research how to make `UltiSnipsEdit` open the appropriate snippets file in `~/.vim/UltiSnips` rather than in project directory. Seem like a really useful functionality targeted at a wrong directory

Comment: I've updated my answer for the edit behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after all the Problem is, that `UltiSnips` does not search the projectfolder for snippets.

If you read `:h UltiSnips-snippet-search-path` you can see, that it looks for all folders defined in `g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories` which are subfolders of a directory defined in the `runtimepath` option.

`:h runtimepath` shows that this depending on the OS but mostly something like:

```
                    Unix: "$HOME/.vim,
                    $VIM/vimfiles,
                    $VIMRUNTIME,
                    $VIM/vimfiles/after,
                    $HOME/.vim/after"
```

Now if you have a plugin manager, the runtimepath will be manipulated. So every folder in your `.vim/bundle` directory will be added to it.

Thats a fact `UltiSnips` actually uses for snippets in plugins.
the `vim-snippets` Plugin for example has a folder `UltiSnips` which is automatically read by `UltiSnips` since the pluginmanager will add the plugin to the `runtimepath`

So for you that means, keep all your snippets in a `UltiSnips` folder somewhere in the `runtimepath`. Usually `~/.vim/UltiSnips`.

There is no possibility for projectspecific snippets (There may be a plugin for that). And I see no reason why there should be projectspecific snippets other then different coding styles. But that is handled by other instruments. If you are interested here is a disscusion about it: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/222

For your issue with the `UltiSnipsEdit` command there is a `g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir` variable. see `:h UltiSnipsEdit`